# Error when installing Office 2007 on Ubuntu Linux 9.10 with Wine

Tags: ubuntu, installation, microsoft-office, wine

I'm trying to install Office 2007 on Ubuntu Linux 9.10 with Wine. when I run `$wine setup.exe`, I get the following error message:

*Applying a Setup customization file requires Windows Installer 3.1 or greater. Please contact your administrator.*

And, unfortunately, I am the administrator. I'm running wine-1.1.35, and I used winetricks to install all necessary DLLs before trying to install:

```
./winetricks gdiplus riched20 riched30 msxml3 msxml4 msxml6 corefonts tahoma vb6run vcrun6 msi2
```

Any ideas? This is very odd, because I used the same procedure to install it on my desktop computer, and it worked fine. (I'm now installing it on my Sony Vaio VGN-SR notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling the windows installer directly from MS.

Comment: success! I downloaded WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe from this page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4